# Correct way to detect mime type in php

Tags: php, mime-types, mime, detect

What is the best and reliable way to detect mime type of a file in php?
The following code which is suggested by many people failed to detect docx file mime type:

```
 $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
 $mime = $finfo->file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); 
 echo $mime; exit;
```

This is printing *application/zip* but it is supposed to be

*application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document*

Comment: `docx`/`pptx`/`xlsx` **are** zip files - just saying. This might be a duplicate of [DOCX File type in PHP finfo_file is application/zip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595183/docx-file-type-in-php-finfo-file-is-application-zip)

Comment: Because a .docx file is a zipped collection of xml files, finfo correctly picks up the fact that it's a zip, but takes it no further. You need to look at the files inside the zip itself to detect that the collection is the appropriate set of files for an OfficeOpenXML word document

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/338087/making-libmagic-file-detect-docx-files/377792#377792) I've ported it to PHP:

```
function getMicrosoftOfficeMimeInfo($file) {
    $fileInfo = array(
        'word/' => array(
            'type'      => 'Microsoft Word 2007+',
            'mime'      => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
            'extension' => 'docx'
        ),
        'ppt/' => array(
            'type'      => 'Microsoft PowerPoint 2007+',
            'mime'      => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
            'extension' => 'pptx'
        ),
        'xl/' => array(
            'type'      => 'Microsoft Excel 2007+',
            'mime'      => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
            'extension' => 'xlsx'
        )
    );

    $pkEscapeSequence = "PK\x03\x04";

    $file = new BinaryFile($file);
    if ($file->bytesAre($pkEscapeSequence, 0x00)) {
        if ($file->bytesAre('[Content_Types].xml', 0x1E)) {
            if ($file->search($pkEscapeSequence, null, 2000)) {
                if ($file->search($pkEscapeSequence, null, 1000)) {
                    $offset = $file->tell() + 26;
                    foreach ($fileInfo as $searchWord => $info) {
                        $file->seek($offset);
                        if ($file->bytesAre($searchWord)) {
                            return $fileInfo[$searchWord];
                        }
                    }
                    return array(
                        'type'      => 'Microsoft OOXML',
                        'mime'      => null,
                        'extension' => null
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

class BinaryFile_Exception extends Exception {}

class BinaryFile_Seek_Method {
    const ABSOLUTE = 1;
    const RELATIVE = 2;
}

class BinaryFile {
    const SEARCH_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

    private $handle;

    public function __construct($file) {
        $this->handle = fopen($file, 'r');
        if ($this->handle === false) {
            throw new BinaryFile_Exception('Cannot open file');
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        fclose($this->handle);
    }

    public function tell() {
        return ftell($this->handle);
    }

    public function seek($offset, $seekMethod = null) {
        if ($offset !== null) {
            if ($seekMethod === null) {
                $seekMethod = BinaryFile_Seek_Method::ABSOLUTE;
            }
            if ($seekMethod === BinaryFile_Seek_Method::RELATIVE) {
                $offset += $this->tell();
            }
            return fseek($this->handle, $offset);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function read($length) {
        return fread($this->handle, $length);
    }

    public function search($string, $offset = null, $maxLength = null, $seekMethod = null) {
        if ($offset !== null) {
            $this->seek($offset);
        } else {
            $offset = $this->tell();
        }

        $bytesRead = 0;
        $bufferSize = ($maxLength !== null ? min(self::SEARCH_BUFFER_SIZE, $maxLength) : self::SEARCH_BUFFER_SIZE);

        while ($read = $this->read($bufferSize)) {
            $bytesRead += strlen($read);
            $search = strpos($read, $string);

            if ($search !== false) {
                $this->seek($offset + $search + strlen($string));
                return true;
            }

            if ($maxLength !== null) {
                $bufferSize = min(self::SEARCH_BUFFER_SIZE, $maxLength - $bytesRead);
                if ($bufferSize == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getBytes($length, $offset = null, $seekMethod = null) {
        $this->seek($offset, $seekMethod);
        $read = $this->read($length);
        return $read;
    }

    public function bytesAre($string, $offset = null, $seekMethod = null) {
        return ($this->getBytes(strlen($string), $offset) == $string);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$info = getMicrosoftOfficeMimeInfo('hi.docx');
/*
    Array
    (
        [type] => Microsoft Word 2007+
        [mime] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
        [extension] => docx
    )
*/

$info = getMicrosoftOfficeMimeInfo('hi.xlsx');
/*
    Array
    (
        [type] => Microsoft Excel 2007+
        [mime] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
        [extension] => xlsx
    )
*/

$info = getMicrosoftOfficeMimeInfo('hi.pptx');
/*
    Array
    (
        [type] => Microsoft PowerPoint 2007+
        [mime] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
        [extension] => pptx
    )
*/

$info = getMicrosoftOfficeMimeInfo('hi.zip');
// bool(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to you mime types config (/etc/magic.mime;/etc/mime.types) mime types you need. Also you can take (google it) ready magic.types file and use mime_magic.magicfile option in php.ini