# Yii file validation to allow video/*

Tags: file-upload, yii2, mime-types

Can anyone tell me that how can I allow all the mime types which starts with video/ in Yii2.

currently my validations are like

```
[['attachmentfile'], 'file','skipOnEmpty'=>FALSE, 'extensions' => 'mp4,3gp,mov,m4v,mpeg,mpg', 'mimeTypes' => 'video/mp4,video/quicktime,video/x-quicktime,video/x-m4v,video/mov,video/3gpp,video/mpeg','on'=>  'create'],
```

now I want to allow each video because I am getting error in some videos uploading. So how can I allow all mime types which starts with video/*

Also please if anyone can tell me that is it a good approach?

Real problem-
I have a video  file which is mp4 and the mime type is video/mp4. When i upload it. My model generates error for mime type. For rest of my videos it is working fine till now. I tried to check mime type on a link online and it is also showing mp4. So I am not sure what is the problem with this video. I am using ffmpeg conversion now so I want to allow each video file to upload and will convert them to mp4. Only this video is creating problem. So if anyone can tell me how can I allow all the video/* mime types

Answer (score 2):

You could disable the mimeType checking with setting `checkExtensionByMimeType` to `false`

[Yii2 Api: checkExtensionByMimeType](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filevalidator.html#$checkExtensionByMimeType-detail)

Other than that you have to add the MimeType your file is returning so that the check for it returns true.

[Yii2 Api: basefilehelper::getMimeType](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basefilehelper.html#getMimeType%28%29-detail)

It could also be your problem that fileinfo doesn't return the correct mimeType. I also had this once on Windows were on Linux it was correct.

[Stackoverflow: Fileinfo returns different mimetype on php version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925710/fileinfo-returns-different-mimetype-on-php-version-5-4-22-and-5-3-3)

Available MimeType Listings could be found here:

[Stackoverflow: PHP / Mime Types - List of mime types publically available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519393/php-mime-types-list-of-mime-types-publically-available)

Comment: Thanks I checked for Yii2 Api: basefilehelper::getMimeType. It really helped me. it is showing mime type- **"application/octet-stream"**. So its a binary file. For future users just to update you can can get mime type by `echo $pp=\yii\helpers\FileHelper::getMimeType($model->attachmentfile->tempName)` Here attachmentfile is my form input. So I am not allowing this file