# How to detect .docx correct MIME other than application/octet-stream

Tags: php, upload, mime-types

I have a website that uploads documents to the server and insert them into Mysql tables.

In the process the server (via PHP) examns the type of the file to decide whether rejecting it or save it, and I do this via posting the

> $_FILES["file"]["type"]

and be sure it equals to:

> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

However, in some cases the posted file type appeares to be:

> application/octet-stream

**Is this because the client doesn't have MS Word installed on the device?**

If this is the case, is it **NOT** safe to verify `application/octet-stream` to be one of the allowed file types? given that it's for generic MIME as per my understanding; which means any file type including `.exe` would be allowed? (it goes without saying what issues would this cause).

Is there some other way to validate the file type `.docx` even if no MS Word installed? or whatever the reason behind such? I have seen other websites allow uploading `.docx` files even from mobile devices that don't have such installed.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to detect mime type in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681453/correct-way-to-detect-mime-type-in-php)

Comment: I have checked the eariler post, it is a different question since it is about how to validate/get the posted file type, however in my case the file is being uploaded to PHP as application/octet-stream which is generic, so my question is why and what is the sloution, hope this suffice

Answer (score 1):

For all file types, you have to go through the [magic number](https://asecuritysite.com/forensics/magic). The mime type can be modified by an attacker.

The code must read the first 3, 4 or 5 bytes of the received file and compare with the desired magic number.