# PHP extend library

Tags: php, oop

I'm using a library to handle my uploads, this is installed via composer.

The library is called [FileUpload](https://github.com/Gargron/fileupload).

As you can see from the documentation, three parts of the library are abstracted so you can create your own custom class if you need to.

> "The reason why the path resolver, the validators and the file system
>   are abstracted, is so you can write your own, fitting your own needs
>   (and also, for unit testing). The library is shipped with a bunch of
>   "simple" implementations which fit the basic needs. You could write a
>   file system implementation that works with Amazon S3, for example."

This is great, but I need to override a function on [this](https://github.com/Gargron/fileupload/blob/master/src/FileUpload/File.php) class.

```
<?php

namespace FileUpload;

class File {
  /**
   * Preset no errors
   * @var mixed
   */
  public $error = 0;

  /**
   * Preset unknown mime type
   * @var string
   */
  public $type  = 'application/octet-stream';

  /**
   * Is the file completely downloaded
   * @var boolean
   */
  public $completed  = false;

  /**
   * Determine file type from path (actual mime type, not extension checking)
   * @param string $path
   */
  public function setTypeFromPath($path) {
    $this->type = finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $path);
  }

  /**
   * Does this file have an image mime type?
   * @return boolean
   */
  public function isImage() {
    return in_array($this->type, array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png'));
  }
}
```

The function I need to override is: setTypeFromPath(). 
This function is using a php function to get the actual mime type of the file.

[finfo_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php), which is fine for images and standard documents but when I try to upload a compressed document e.g docx, potx it doesn't pass my validation as the mime type is returned as **application/zip.**

My validation:

```
$validator = new FileUpload\Validator\Simple(1024 * 1024 * 10, array(
                'application/msword',
                'application/word',
                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template',
                'application/pdf',
                'application/x-pdf',
                ' application/acrobat',
                'applications/vnd.pdf'
            ), $_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Have your tried to add more mime types to your server?

Comment: @sectus I have all correct mime types. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595183/docx-file-type-in-php-finfo-file-is-application-zip