# Detecting Word documents

Tags: php

I am trying to detecting Word documents but it fails for some Word documents. I can open the problematic documents just fine in Word and extract them since they are basically just zip files.

I have also tried adding `msooxml` to `/etc/magic` on my Ubuntu 18.04 server and restart nginx & PHP FPM with no luck. I use PHP 7.4.4

- Is there a way to check if `msooxml` are used?
- Do you any suggestions
  to make it work?

Here is my code:

```
$file = 'broken.docx';

$mime = mime_content_type($file);

echo '<p>'.$mime.'</p>';

$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME, 'msooxml');

echo '<p>'.$finfo->file($file).'</p>';
```

Result:

```
application/octet-stream

application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

Expected result:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; charset=binary
```

`msooxml` file taken from: https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/msooxml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DOCX File type in PHP finfo\_file is application/zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595183/docx-file-type-in-php-finfo-file-is-application-zip)

Comment: I doesn't really answer my question and it seems the answers in your link is a bit unclear.